# Wrap text in excel file using uipath

Tags: uipath, rpa, uipath-studio

xlsx file, it has one sheet, I need to use wrap text for the entire sheet. How can I achieve it using UiPath?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use the Uipath UI Automation

```
 1. Open the excel sheet
 2. select the whole sheet
 3. Click the wrap button from the toolbar
```